# Trials achievement in Ultra Street Fighter IV

Tags: achievements, ultra-street-fighter-iv

In USFIV there's the option of doing "ultra trials" instead of the SSFIV:AE "trials". If I complete the ultra trials, will I get the "Trial Athlete" achievement?

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't. You need to complete the older trials.